# how to reduce the size of the images in a website?

Tags: image

We recently launched our new website. It is taking much time to load as the images are very huge. Now we want to reduce the size of all images. But resizing every image individually will consume much time. Instead i want to control all images from backend. what is the best way out?

Comment: What language is your site written in?

Comment: As @Adam Hopkinson is leading, you could do this with PHP and the ImageMagic extensions (possibly with gd). Alternatively, you could just use ImageMagic tools or on a Linux CLI or a find a batch image processor in Windows Server. Either way, you could tune image quality and resolution to reduce fike size and load times.

Comment: @Adam Hopkinson. We used C#.Net